# AS3: how do i stop two of the same function from playing at once?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash

i am using AS3 to create a function that will automatically play a movieclip all the way through and then remove it. my project is going to have a lot of animated cutscenes, so id like to be able to call this function, use the cutscene id like as a parameter, and then move on to the next. the problem is, im trying to use the function multiple times in a row to play clips sequentially, but they're all playing at the same time. is there a fix, or a better way to do this altogether?

```
playClip(new a_walk); //find a way to make these stop playing at the same time 
playClip(new a_door);
//a_walk and a_door are the AS linkage class names for the movieclips im referring to 

function playClip (clip:MovieClip):void {
addChildAt(clip, 0);
clip.mask = myMask;
clip.x=412.4;
clip.y=244.5;

clip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkframes);
    function checkframes(event:Event) {
        if (clip.currentFrame == clip.totalFrames) {
            //trace("wow! youre an idiot!"); 
            if (clip.parent) {
                clip.parent.removeChild(clip);
                trace (100);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like  you have a function defined inside another function definition.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but all your functions ought to be at the base level, then, if you need a function inside another function, you just call that function from inside the other function... don't define the function inside another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a mechanism to play a queue of MovieClips?  If so, here is a way you can accomplish this:

```
//create an array with the clips you want to play (in order), in my example here, the items can be a MovieClip derived Class, or a MovieClip instance
var playQueue:Array = [a_walk, a_door];

//create a var to store the currently playing clip
var currentClip:MovieClip;

playNext(); //call this when you want the queue of clips to start playing

function playNext():void {
    //if there was an item previously playing (currentClip has a value), stop it and remove it/dispose of it
    if(currentClip){
        currentClip.stop(); //stop it from playing
        currentClip.addFrameScript(currentClip.totalFrames-1, null); //remove the frame script that was added
        currentClip.parent.removeChild(currentClip); //remove it from the display
        currentClip = null;
    }   

    //check if there's anything left to play
    if(playQueue.length < 1) return;

    var nextItem:* = playQueue.shift(); //shift retrieves and removes the first item in the array;

    if(nextItem is Class){
        //if it's a class, instantiate it
        currentClip = new nextItem();
    }else{
        currentClip = MovieClip(nextItem);
    }

    //initialize the movie clip
    addChildAt(currentClip, 0);
    currentClip.gotoAndPlay(1);

    //this is just what you were doing before:
    currentClip.mask = myMask;
    currentClip.x=412.4;
    currentClip.y=244.5;

    //add a command on the last frame of the movie clip to play the next item in the queue
    currentClip.addFrameScript(currentClip.totalFrames-1, playNext);

    //addFrameScript is 0 based, so 0 would refer to the first frame.  This is why we subtract 1 to get the last frame
}
```

I should note, that `addFrameScript` is an undocumented function.  It serves as a nice shortcut so you don't have to have an `ENTER_FRAME` listener checking `currentFrame` vs. `totalFrames`.   Being undocumented however, one can not count on it's continued existence in future versions of the Flash/AIR runtimes (though it's been around for a long long time)

Comment: thanks, this works! it looks like the using an array as the queue is a more efficient way of playing the clips. i think i understand the function for the most part, but im confused on the significance of a few lines. how come if `nextItem` isnt a `Class` then `currentClip` becomes `MovieClip(nextItem)` ? i dont really understand the `MovieClip(nextItem)` part at all. and why when adding the frame script do you subtract 1 from the clip's `totalFrames`? but anyways, thanks for improving my code!

Comment: AddFrameScript is 0 based (unlike gotoAndStop / currentFrame which are 1 based).   So with addFrameScript the first frame is 0,  with currentFrame and gotoAndStop the first frame is 1...

Comment: I just made is so you could put an instance in the array as well,  so if you already had a instantiated MovieClip (on the timeline for instance) - the MovieClip(nextItem) is just telling the compiler that nextItem is indeed a MovieClip (as it could possibly be a Class reference)

Comment: thanks for explaining, i understand now. its kind of strange that AS3 would make addframescript 0 based but other script (idk commands? functions?) start at 1 lol.

Comment: hey, im trying to convert this code from the timeline to a class (the main class). since the last line of the pre-existing code loops the function through means of each object's timeline, im trying to find a way to loop through the array from within the function. nothing seems to be working, do you have any tips? im new to OOP...

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  The code should work fine as part of your main class.   If you're getting errors and need help, it might be best to ask a new question and post all the new details (code you're trying, the exact errors or problem etc.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734544/what-do-i-replace-addframescript-with-in-object-oriented-as3

Answer (score 0):

### note

This answer is a work in progress. I'm waiting on a response from the OP.

```
// playClip(new a_door); don't call this yet, or they will just both play. 
var clipData:CustomClass = new CustomClass(); // add an instance of a custom class to hold the value of the movie     
//clip being played (so that you can use this value later in the event handler.)
// it will also hold a value of the next clip
clipData._currentClip = a_walk;
clipData._nextClip = a_door;
playClip(new a_walk); 

function playClip (clip:MovieClip):void {
    addChildAt(clip, 0);
    clip.mask = myMask;
    clip.x=412.4;
    clip.y=244.5;
    clip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkframes);
}

function checkframes(event:Event) {
    if (clipData._currentClip.currentFrame == clipData._currentClip.totalFrames) {
        //trace("wow! youre an idiot!"); 
        if (clipData._currentClip.parent) {
            playClip(clipData._nextClip);
            clipData._currentClip.parent.removeChild(clipData._currentClip);
            clipData._currentClip = clipData._nextClip; // moves the clips down
            //clipData._nextClip = here we have 
//a problem. Do these clips play in a set 
//order, first to last? Or do the play out of 
//order jumping back and forth? If so, how 
//are you planning on controlling which clip 
//plays next? 
            trace (100);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't checked this in Flash yet to see if it works, but I noticed that you are defining a function inside another function, which I don't think is good practice, so this might clean things up for you.  Give it a try and let us know.

I'll try to fix my code above when I get a chance.  In the meantime, you answered my question about playing the clips in order, so a simple solution would be to put all the clips in an array and then play them by `playClip(clipArray[i])` and then when the clip ends and gets removed, do `i++` and call the same function `playClip(clipArray[i])` which will play the next clip in the array.

Comment: thanks for cleaning things up for me, but both of the functions are still executing at the same time. but strangely enough, now if i plant two of these functions sequentially, the first one will loop forever and the second one never shows up. if there is only one function call then the code works fine. your code did give me an idea, though. i thought i could check _currentClip in between each function call to stop them all from playing at once. although ive tried putting it a few different ways and nothing seems to be working...?

Comment: @carrmx they both execute because you call them one right after the other. Why wouldn't they both execute? You need to only call the second one when you have removed or stopped the first one, not immediately after it.

Comment: what is a CustomClass()? my compiler is giving me two errors, telling me it doesnt recognize this data type.

Comment: also, yes, the clips only play from first to last--i didnt have any jumping in mind.

Comment: CustomClass is something I made up. You'd have to actually make a custom class and replace CustomClass with your class name.

Comment: oh! hey, thanks for showing that to me. i didn't know variables could do that.